# Date and Time Format in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have this codes:

```
class ClockLabel extends JLabel implements ActionListener {

    public ClockLabel() {
        super("" + new java.util.Date());
       Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
       t.start();
    }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      txtclock.setText((new java.util.Date()).toString());
   }
 }
```

and my output is

```
Wed Feb 06 14:22:44 CST 2013
```

how can I change my output in this format

```
"MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: i tried to input it super("" + new java.util.Date("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

Comment: Googling `java format date` gives `SimpleDateFormat` as a first link.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
txtclock.setText(f.format(new java.util.Date()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `SimpleDateFormat` class. You can construct the instance of `SimpleDateformat with patteryn`"MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"`and pass the date object in`format()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String sDate= sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [simple date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
@Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      txtclock.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date()));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as

```
class ClockLabel extends JLabel implements ActionListener {
    java.util.Date date;
    public ClockLabel() {
        super(getStrVAl());
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        txtclock.setText(getStrVAl());
    }

    public String getStrVAl() {
        date=new java.util.Date();
        String val=date.getMonth().toString()+" "+date.getDate().toString()+" "+date.getYear().toString()+" "date.getHours().toString()+":"+date.getMinutes().toString()+":"+date.getSeconds()().toString()+" ");
        return val;
    }
}
```